# Searching for files with dir - Multiple hits

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that iterate through folders and use the "dir"-function to find out if a file exist in the active folder, and puts the filename in a cell.

The problem is that it might be two or more files satisfies the search.

```
Dir(subfolder & "\Kommunesvar*")
```

How can I get both two results in a specified subfolder if there are two files starting with "Kommunesvar"? Dir returns the filename, but I want both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you using `DIR`. The below code will give you all the files which start with `Kommunesvar` and are Excel Files.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim subfolder As String
    Dim sDir

    subfolder = "C:\Temp"

    sDir = Dir$(subfolder & "\Kommunesvar*.xls*", vbNormal)

    Do Until LenB(sDir) = 0
        Debug.Print subfolder & sDir
        sDir = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```

If you want to store all the files names in one variable then you can use this as well.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim subfolder As String, FileNames As String
    Dim sDir

    subfolder = "C:\Temp"

    sDir = Dir$(subfolder & "\Kommunesvar*.xls*", vbNormal)

    Do Until LenB(sDir) = 0
        If FileNames <> "" Then
            FileNames = FileNames & "; " & subfolder & sDir
        Else
            FileNames = subfolder & sDir
        End If
        sDir = Dir$
    Loop

    Debug.Print FileNames
End Sub
```

Comment: That's perfect :) I needed a macro to iterate through 260 folders and create a hyperlink to each file that satisfied the specified string, in the row corresponding the active folder. Worked like a charm now :)