# range matrix A1:Q38 from 1400 files & listing as single column in new workbook row A1 followed by row A2 etc

Tags: excel, vba

1400 separate excell files need to take all data from each file row by row from range A1:Q38. need that data in a single column list in order of each original row. Need to read row A1:Q1 and write to A1:A17 then read A2:Q2 and write to A18:A34 continue until each file is read. Need data in a new workbook. Would like to ignore writing empty cells to new list if possible. following code will do job in one worksheet. Need it to work against 1400 files programmatically.

```
Sub readvalues()

row2 = 1
For Row = 1 To 38
For col = 1 To 17
READCELL = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, col).Value
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(row2, 1) = READCELL
row2 = row2 + 1
Next col
Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: -"Need data in a new workbook. ", Did you mean `WorkSheet`?

Comment: You need to loop through a directory. This link is a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291573/searching-for-files-with-dir-multiple-hits ... search `[excel-vba] dir` on SO to find more

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is called `Transpose`. `PasteSpecial` allows you to paste using transposed cells. (Rows become columns and columns become rows, as in a Matrix)

```
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim rowCount As Integer
rowCount = 1

Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
targetWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:/MyData/TransposedRow" & rowCount

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Copy
targetWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

rowCount = rowCount + 1
```

Comment: to question did I mean worksheet no new workbook to loop link thanks and to code listed got error 34 changed line to targetsheet.usedrange.rows it ran no errors but i got 38 worksheets with 1 column per sheet i need 1 worksheet in 1 workbook with 1 column of single list data thanks but not quite it

Comment: @user1771885 I don't know if the edited answer will work (I wonder if the newly created workbook's sheets can be modified)

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted 1 column per sheet, will modifiy that!

Comment: when I ran the original code you posted debug error 34 popped up I added the targetsheet. to that line. It then ran no errors but I ended up with 38 worksheets all with 1 column of data from the original single 17 x 38 matrix sheet  close but not it I need that data in a single sheet as a single column oh your question could the sheets be modified not sure what you mean thanks

Comment: So you want data copied into 1 single `WorkBook`, containing  1 single `Worksheet` ?

Comment: end result would be read data from 1400 workbooks all containing 1 worksheet with data in a 17x38 matrix, then write that data to 1 workbook with 1 worksheet with 1 column listing all of the read data from the 1400 files that 1 column would be A and the data would be in the order of the orignal worksheets rows  one row stacked on top of the next row and so on

Comment: I tried this latest code posting and got errors  first error appears to be the front slash used in the C:/mydata/ I changed them to back slashes (\\) and that error went away then ran it again and new runtime error 1004 on the line targetworkbook.sheets  when error occurs cursor is on sheet 2 with cell A1 selected and there is no data in it.  not sure about that error will have to think   thanks