# Collating Excel Worksheets Imbedded in Powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

Background:  I am on the backend of an effort to capture and collate data collected in PowerPoint template form.   A template was distributed.  The result is ~150 PowerPoint 2010 presentations of ~30 slides each.  ~15 of slides in each presentation contain an imbedded XLS.

Benefit to community:  Examples of PowerPoint to Excel techniques and in general MS Office techniques vs. solely one MS Office tool.

Problem:  I'm only an introductory VBA developer.  I seem to find many examples how to get Excel data to PowerPoint, but not much (!) about this seemingly backward approach of data from PowerPoint into Excel.  PeltierTech.com gets me close.  I found some texts but need a solution before I can get through them.

Need:
1) Loop through all presentations (.PPTX) in a folder (open/close)
2) Inspect each slide in each presentation for an imbedded XLS
3) If found
      a) Copy the imbedded source XLS range (not image)
      b) Find the last row of the target XLS tab
      c) Write the .PPTX name into tab column A
      d) Paste the source XLS into target Excel column B

Finally I would prefer the "host" VBA be Excel.

The ideal result is a single .XLSX with ~15 tabs.  The resultant data can be scrubbed for unique headers and converted into a pivotable dataset.

This doesn't appear the most to be the most challenging exercise.  I think I'm hung on combining the two object models in a single set of procedures.  (Yes, the references are correctly set ;-) )

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Are you looking for someone to help you with code that isn't quite working?  If so, post the code, explain in detail what isn't working and indicate on what line/s the failure seems to be occurring.  If you're looking for someone to write the solution, this isn't the place to ask.

Comment: I understand Steve.  The stuff I've written at this time is too convoluted.  I welcome any snippets to direct me down the right path.

Comment: Some parts of you question have already been answered elsewhere. [Looping files in the dir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291573/searching-for-files-with-dir-multiple-hits/11291718#11291718)

Comment: You may get better google results if you search for "embedded".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I wrote to extract one chart data from PP file (code is in a excel module). I've commented the code so you will be able to build your own loops to this, but the mechanics of extracting chart data from PP-file via Excel-VBA is as in the following block -

```
'"Microsoft PowerPoint xx.x Object Library" needed to be installed
'
Sub OpenPPandCopyChartData()
    'Create an instance of Powerpoint
    Dim PPT As Object
    Set PPT = CreateObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Open the powerpoint file
    Dim pp As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set pp = PPT.Presentations.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Presentation1.pptx", ReadOnly:=msoTrue)

    'Select the wanted slide
    Dim ps As PowerPoint.slide
    Set ps = pp.Slides(1)

    'Select the shape
    Dim sh As PowerPoint.Shape
    Set sh = ps.Shapes(2)
    'You can make your own loop to check all the shapes if they contain a chart by using HasChart Method
    Debug.Print sh.HasChart = msoTrue


    'Select the shape that has chart and activate
    sh.Chart.ChartData.Activate

    'Set the activated workbook to a variable
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = sh.Chart.ChartData.Workbook

    'Select the sheet the data is contained
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    'Select the range and copy
    ws.UsedRange.Copy

    'Set where to copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    wb.Close
    pp.Close
    PPT.Quit
End Sub
```

The code opens the PPT.file in the same folder that the Excel file is in and selects Slide(1) and Shape(2) from that slide. Then it activates the chart data (if not present this code will cause a subscript out of range error, so on your own code a data checking will be needed) and copies it to the Excel that the sub was started in.

Comment: Thanks, uh, SickD ;-)   I think I have the loops so these are statements I need or very close.  Will keep apprised.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, and to get the sheet where the data contains you can use `Set ws = wb.Sheets(Mid(sh.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula, 9, -9 + InStr(1, sh.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula, "!")))` . Getting the range is a tricky part, but i suppose `UsedRange` most likely applies to most cases.

Comment: I read about some dangers with UsedRange but it seems to work fine for my instance... Thanks SD.   I will post my final solution in a few days for others.  Truly appreciated....